# Average signal strength in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, networking

I want to display device signal strength in my public app.

I searched a lot on this community and not able to get public API to do the same.
But I come across one app called '**CoverageMap**' where user can perform test for type 'signal only' and app shows result in icon like green, orange and red.

My question is: How this app is calculating average signal strength?

What does this result parameter stands for?

Comment: what signal strength you are talking about? GSM signal strength, Wifi signal strength, or GPS signal strength?

Comment: @AlexWein: are above GSM signal strength, Wifi signal strength, or GPS signal strength parameters are possible in iOS?

Comment: I think none of the above three. For Apple yes, but not using allowed API

Answer (score 1):

If you would have read the App store description of CoverageMap, then you would know that they measure the data transmission speed.
GSM Field strength is measured in dBm, I doubt that the App outputs that. 
Probably they assign a color value (orange green) related to the data speed measured.

Comment: I was thinking the same. But there are two test cases 'Signal and Data' and 'Signal only'. So do you mean they are using same process but does not display data rate when selected 'Signal only'?

Comment: Probably. You may research a bit if apple provides an APOI to get the signal value, at least the number of bar/points in the status bar. If not you also could create an screenshot and by image recognition count the number of bars